# What is the meaning of "yet" in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "yet" in the next sentence?

> This object, relatively nearby, offers the best opportunity **yet** to build a good understanding of how such jets actually work

Comment: Up to this point.

Comment: "Offers the best opportunity so far"

Comment: defn 2 here: amazing what you can discover in a dictionary.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yet

Comment: @MaxWilliams The problem is that this *yet* doesn't look like it can be an adverb (even though it is). Why? Because it is postmodifying a noun. Adverbs, according to traditional grammar cannot modify nouns at all. So this would lead a language student, for example, to analyse this as *yet* the conjunction. "It is small yet mighty" for exammple. There is no evidence from your dictionary definition whatsoever that this is the same *yet*. Their *yet*s are all used like normal adverbs. The interesting issue then for this site ( a site for linguists and serious language enthusiasts) is  ...

Comment: @MaxWilliams ... how come we have an adverb modifying a noun? And how do we know it's not the conjunction?

Comment: Generally, when a word has several meanings, as in this case, one considers the different meanings and decides which one fits best into the context of the sentence.  The meaning you mention in "small yet mighty", which basically means "and, suprisingly,", doesn't fit the context of the original sentence.

Comment: If you are asking "How did this confusing variety of meanings come to be applied to this single word?", then that's a more complicated question which i'm not going to tackle.  You asked what it means in the contex of that sentence.  I told you.  If you want to know about the history of the word then ask a different question.

Comment: @MaxWilliams No, I'm saying that this usage does not fit with the information that your dictionary gives, because this seemingly is not the **adverb** *yet*.  Your dictionary entry is for an adverb! (I'm playing, I just wanted to point out that OP has very good reason to ask about what this word means in this context given the grammar of the sentence) ;-)

Comment: Read this:  http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv134.shtml

Answer (score 1):

The meaning seems to be Merriam-Webster's [2a1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yet): "up to now: so far."

"Yet" here is indeed an adverb. Adverbs can also modify adjectives, and in this case, it seems to be modifying "best," as in, "best yet."

Comment: Exactly. _The best `X` yet_ is a fixed formula.